# Requesting a change of project at the beginning of an internship

Tags: career-development, internship, internal-transfer

I know there is a similar question before on a similar topic. My case is a bit different. I'm currently a student in college. Previously, I had research experience in quantum computing for a few months, and then I lost interest and switched to Machine Learning for around 8 months already. Recently, I got accepted on an internship, and there was no information on what team I would be in when I received my acceptance letter. I just got informed that I will be working in a Quantum Computing group. Actually, this is a very big company that has groups working on both Machine Learning and Quantum Computing. I would like to change to a Machine Learning group because that more aligns with my current interest. I have no idea why I got allocated to Quantum Computing team. That may be because I've used the company software for my quantum computing research. So, my questions are:

- Is it possible for me at this point (where I just got an acceptance letter a few days ago and as a lowly intern) to ask for a change in the project? Personally, I don't think I would be able to contribute much if I don't have interest in what I am working on, but I don't think I can say this to my employer
- If the answer for the first question is yes, then how should I ask them? What for and against reasoning should I take into account?

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible for me at this point (where I just got acceptance letter a few days ago and as a lowly intern) to ask for a change in project?

Given that you just got the acceptance letter, this is a good time to ask if it's possible to switch to a machine learning group. Typically, at large companies each group is allocated a fixed number of interns, but they will try to match you up with groups that match your skills and interests.

> ... How should I ask them? What for and against reasoning should I take into account?

I would just email the point of contact at the company. Thank them for the internship and reiterate your interest in working for the company. Then express your interest in switching to a more machine learning focused group, because of your own interest in machine learning and the work you've done in the last 8 months.

I don't recommend completely eliminating the possibility of working for the quantum computing group or you may end up with no internship unless you're okay with that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. "Then express your interest in switching to a more machine learning focused group", the only two reasonings that I have right now is that I have been working more in this field than Quantum Computing and that  I'm currently more interested in this field. I'm quite afraid that this wouldn't be strong enough to make a change. At the same time, I also don't want to eliminate the possibility of working for the quantum computing group either.

Comment: @KhaHo Still it's worth asking if it's possible to switch to ML even if the eventual answer is no.

Comment: Some updates: I emailed them last Thursday night about changing to a more Machine Learning focused team. Until now, there is still no response from my employer ... Should I send another email asking for updates or keep waiting patiently?